# Attribute in junction table depends on the primary key

Tags: mysql, attributes, foreign-keys, junction-table

I have a junction table to set up a many-to-many relationship between properties and their policies

The property_id and policy_id form the primary key.

As an additional attribute I wish to store a value or have a foreign key reference. The value can refer to a range of things, e.g. number of days, the fine amount, or even link to a fine amount stored in another table. So the value’s type of what it refers to isn’t consistent - this doesn’t seem right.

As an alternative, I could create multiple attributes and then keep all but one null for a given data record, however, I don’t like that as I’d have to increase the number of attributes in the table over time if other policies were ever added.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: 'The property_id and policy_id form the primary key.' -that cannot be right if a property can have many policies. Also what ever belongs to a policy should be in the policy table and if there are things that don't sit easily there they should be in separate table(s) For example premium payments would be in a transactions table, claims would be in a claim history table etc

Comment: @P.Salmon there is a composite key for that very reason - to allow multiple policies per property. Also the value for the policy depends also on the property (E.g. one property’s cancellation fee may be different to another) hence I placed it in the junction table.

Comment: What you seem to be describing is the entity-attribute-value (EAV) data model, which is a way to have flexible set of properties in an otherwise inflexible relational database world. One of the challenges of EAV is storing values for different data types.